# Filter matrix by count of odd numbers per row

Tags: r

Having a matrix A like:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
  [1,]   11   14   17   21   23   25
  [2,]   12   15   18   24   26   28
  [3,]   13   15   19   21   25   29
```

I want to filter all rows that have per row count of odd numbers < 2

So the matrix (result) should contain only row 2 of matrix A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the rows with `apply` specifying `MARGIN =1`, create a logical `vector` to subset the matrix 'm1'

```
m1[apply(m1, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(x %% 2) < 2),, drop = FALSE]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   12   15   18   24   26   28
```

Or with `rowSums`

```
m1[rowSums((m1 %%2)) <2, , drop = FALSE]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]   12   15   18   24   26   28
```

EDIT: Based on @lmo's comments

#### data

```
m1 <- structure(c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 17, 18, 19, 21, 24, 21, 23, 
     26, 25, 25, 28, 29), .Dim = c(3L, 6L))
```

Comment: As a minor update, the output of `sum(x %% 2 ==1)`  is identical to `sum(x %% 2)` and the latter involves fewer computations.

Comment: @lmo Thanks, I was coding it before getting the data.  You are right.  Thanks